# Нужно вывести текст из адресной строки на страницу

Tags: php, html

Учу `php` второй день, поэтому ошибка скорее всего глупая. Нужна Ваша помощь!

html:

```
<div id='signin' class='modal-window'>
  <h2 style='text-align:center'>Sign In</h2> <br>
  <form action=/controller.php method 'post'>
        <input type='hidden' name='page' value='StartPage'/>
        <input type='hidden' name='command' value='SignIn'/>
        <label class='modal-label'>Username:</label>
        <input type='text' name='username' placeholder='Enter username'/><br>
        <label class='modal-label'>Password:</label>
        <input type='password' name='password' placeholder='Enter password'/><br><br>
        <button type='submit' value='Submit'>Submit</button>
        <button type='reset' value='Reset'>Reset</button>
        <button id='cancel-signin' type='cancel' value='Cancel'>Cancel</button>
    </form>
</div>
<div id='join' class='modal-window'>
    <h2 style='text-align:center'>Join</h2><br>
    <form action=/controller.php method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='page' value='StartPage'/>
    <input type='hidden' name='command' value='Join'/>
    <label class='modal-label'>Username:</label>
    <input type='text' name='username' placeholder='Enter username' /><br>
    <label class='modal-label'>Password:</label>
    <input type='password' name='password' placeholder='Enter password' /><br>
    <label class='modal-label'>Email:</label>
    <input type='text' name='email' placeholder='Enter email address' /><br><br>
    <button type='submit' value='Submit'>Submit</button>
    <button type='reset' value='Reset'>Reset</button>
    <button id='cancel-join' type='cancel' value='Cancel'>Cancel</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

PHP:

```
<html>
    <body>
    <?php

    if (isset($_POST['page'])=='StartPage')// When commands come from StartPage
    {
       $command = isset($_POST['command']);
       switch($command) { // When a command is sent from the client
           case 'SignIn': // With username and password
               echo "command" . $command;
               $username = $_POST['username'];
               echo "username". $username;
               $password = $_POST['password'];
               echo "password". $password;
               break;
           case 'Join':
               echo "command" . $command;
               $username = $_POST['username'];
               echo "username". $username;
               $password = $_POST['password'];
               echo "password". $password;
   }
   }
   ?>
   </body>
   </html>
```

вывод такой нужен примерно:
`command = SignIn(или Joinn), username = "введенный username", password = "какой-то пароль" и email если command == Join`

Comment: У вас в коде опечатка, потеряли `=` в `<form ... method 'post'>`

Comment: Спасибо,исправил!Но все равно ошибка Notice: Undefined index: page in D:\xampp\htdocs\controller.php on line 5

Comment: Проверил у себя, ошибок нет. Единственное, стоит заменить `if (isset($_POST['page'])=='StartPage')` на `if (isset($_POST['page']) && $_POST['page']=='StartPage')`

Comment: Спасибо!А нормально что страница controller.php пустая или это у меня уже с сервером/браузером проблемы?

Comment: что странно, с Join все работает

Comment: При прямом заходе на контроллер ничего не отобразится, т.к. первая часть условия проверяет передан ли параметр ’page’. А если заполнить форму и нажать submit, то должно отобразиться

Comment: ну да, я про сабмит и говорю).Просто странно что с Join работает а SignIn нет(просто пустая страница).

Answer (score 1):

Функция [isset](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.isset.php) определяет, была ли установлена переменная значением отличным от NULL и возвращает значение типа `bool`, поэтому у вас в `$command` не текст команды. Вам нужно просто заменить

```
$command = isset($_POST['command']);
```

на

```
$command = $_POST['command'];
```

Comment: Стоит также заметить что и `isset($_POST['page'])=='StartPage'` бессмысленно.

Comment: Спасибо, поменял обратно.Я изначально так и писал, просто в поисках ответа почему не работает уже все методом тыка исправлял, и ставил isset везде.Вернулся к изначальной ошибке Notice: Undefined index: page in D:\xampp\htdocs\controller.php on line 5